# create log file on a daily basis for my spring project using log4j.

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I want to create error log file on daily basis for my spring project .I thought, i can get system date and check weather it is same day or diff day , but what will i do , if there is a wrong system date occurred by low CMOS battery.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use log4j daily rolling appender as follows:

```
<appender name="Daily" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
 <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/test.log" />
 <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
 <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %l - %m%n" />
 </layout>
</appender>
```

As to trying to work with a wrong clock there isn't an option!

Hope that helps.